# How can I do search and replace in C Sharp using perl?

Tags: c#, perl, replace, full-text-search, locale

I have the following code for replacing the first occurrence of `searchTerm?` in a given file, with the corresponding `replacement?`. For example if `searchTerm1` is `foo`, `replacement1` is `bar`, and `foo` exists in the file then `foo` is replaced with `bar`.

However, the search and replace is not executed. Instead I get the error message shown after the code below.

**Code**

```
string arguments = $"-i -pe \'s/{searchTerm1}/{replacement1}/; s/{searchTerm2}/{replacement2}/; s/{searchTerm3}/{replacement3}/; s/{searchTerm4}/{replacement4}/\'" + " " + file;

            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("perl", arguments);

            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            Process process = new Process();


            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

            process.Start();
```

**Error message**

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "en",
    LC_NUMERIC = "C",
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be one big argument containing spaces? If so, it should be double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`).

Comment: For starters, the cmd shell uses `"..."` to quote, not `'...'`

Comment: @itsme86 thanks. Thats solved the second error. In the terminal using single quotes (i.e. `-e '...'`works fine. Why's it different in C Sharp?

Comment: @ikegami I'm on MacOs and in a terminal I can use `'...'` to quote. Why can I not use `'...'` to quote when calling `perl` from C Sharp where as on the command line both `'...'` and `"..."` can be used to quote `perl -e`'s argument?

Comment: For simple change/replace, you do not need dynamic to generate dynamic perl. SED will be easier (quoting, etc). If you have <N> replacement, consider passing them to a perl program for dynamic subsiution.